# How do I read a text file in LISP?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a .txt file like this:

```
0 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

And i want LISP to read the text file and generate two lists, the first one with the first nine values of the text file and the second one with the next nine values. Like these: List1 = (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8), List2 = (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8).
I have these code:

```
(DEFUN text() 
  (SETQ l NIL)
  (LOOP
   (UNLESS (NULL l) (SETQ LST1 (LIST (READ l)(READ l)(READ l)(READ l)(READ l)(READ l)(READ l)(READ l)(READ l)) 
                          LST2 (LIST (READ l)(READ l)(READ l)(READ l)(READ l)(READ l)(READ l)(READ l)(READ l)) 
                          eb (LST1) em (LST2))
           (CLOSE l) (RETURN (ASTAR LST1 LST2)))
   (SETQ l (OPEN filename :if-does-not-exist nil))))
```

Comment: That doesn't look like the correct use of the `loop` macro. Notice also that you have created a recursive function since you are calling `read` 18 times from `read`.. Each of them will call `read` 18 times again and again and again.....

Comment: Don't call your function `read`, that's the name of a standard CL function.

Comment: @Sylwester Loop admits a simple form (a looping progn), but the usage is not pretty here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Don't use SETQ with undeclared *global* variables, use local bindings with `let`. Global variables make your code fragile w.r.t. side-effects and clutter the global namespace.
- Don't copy paste or painfully rewrite the same thing over and over, use a loop
- Don't call open/close yourself unless necessary, prefer `with-open-file`.
- You don't need to write in uppercase

### Two nested loops

```
(defun read-18-lines-of-integers-in-two-lists (file)
  (with-open-file (in file)
    (loop repeat 2
          collect (loop repeat 9
                        collect (parse-integer (read-line in))))))
```

### Example

```
(read-18-lines-of-integers-in-two-lists #P"/tmp/test")
=> ((0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))
```